# Multidimensional Array Not finding Index on Second Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am pushing to a multidimensional array here is the code:

```
modelValuesArray["input"]["'"+index+"'"] = $('.' + index).attr("value");
```

Without the speech marks outside of index it does not work.

However on the next loop it then sees it as ""index"", so does not work..

How do I push to the array without needing the speech marks?

Thanks in advance

Alistair

Comment: `modelValuesArray["input"][index] = $('.' + index).attr("value");`

Comment: it doesnt push to the array without speech marks?

Comment: I don't see any reference to any multidimensional array here.

Comment: What are the values of `index`?

Comment: Show the `modelValuesArray`.

Comment: And the rest of the code, like the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating modelValuesArray and modelValuesArray["input"] as objects, if you use a string as key e.g. "input" .. you will not see any values when you iterate over it - use integers instead.

```
const arr = [];
arr[0] = "zero";
arr["index"] = "one";

arr.forEach() ===> "zero"
Object.values(arr).forEach() ===> "zero" "one"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var modelValuesArray = [];
var index = 1;
modelValuesArray["input"] = [$('.' + index).attr("value")];

console.log(modelValuesArray["input"][index-1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="1" value="Hello !!"/>
```